# Why is a lycanthrope weaker in beast form than in hybrid form?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

From what I can tell, a lycanthrope is much weaker in its full beast form than in it's hybrid form. Excluding the werebear, a lycanthrope cannot use multiattack if it is in beast form, it can only use it in hybrid or humanoid form.

The werewolf for example, only gets one attack on its turn if it is in beast form. On top of this it can only claw at people, can't bite. And yet it can bite and claw on the same turn if it is in its hybrid form, which I find very confusing. It seems to me that, unless you are like a level 20 barbarian for example, the body of a human would not be stronger than that of a werewolf in beast form. Which would mean that the hybrid form should be weaker than the beast form. Can someone explain to me why this is not the case?

Comment: Do you expect a rules-based answer, lore-based answer or just some plausible explanation?

Comment: I don't see an errata on it (yet) but at least in the case of weretiger I can't possibly fathom that this was not erroneous. Power is not necessarily only dependent on damage as well. But anything that we put forth as an answer would be conjecture without developer input which seems scarce on these critters.

Comment: It seems to be asking a very similar question to this one, which was not closed: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125325/what-makes-half-orcs-stronger-than-full-orcs

Comment: @Medix2 That one was nearly closed, but was edited to resolve the problem.

Comment: Are you entirely clear on what the different forms are? Beast form is the animal form, like Twilight. Hybrid is what you see in movies like Underworld where they're upright and humanoid (the most dangerous form.) And of course base form is their normal race. Does this information help with respect to what you are asking? Does it provide a little more clarity to help refine your question?